# php instance error, Not found

Tags: php, class, telegram

I try to learn MadelineProto for make a my telegram userBot.
When I make the instance of the API class, I get this Error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'API' not found in /var/www/html/projects/quotidiano/MadelineProto/src/danog/MadelineProto/test.php:3

The code is this:

```
$MadelineProto = new API();

$inputFile = $MadelineProto->upload('pippo.txt', 'pluto.txt');
// Generate an inputMedia object and store it in $inputMedia, see tests/testing.php
$MadelineProto->messages->sendMedia(['peer' => 'xxxxxx', 'media' => $inputMedia]);

$inputEncryptedFile = $MadelineProto->upload_encrypted('pippo.txt', 'pippo.txt');
```

Comment: The class `API` is not found. Does it exist?

Comment: did you include the file with the class?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these functions :

```
include("PATHTOTHEFILE/FILE.PHP"); 
include_once("PATHTOTHEFILE/FILE.PHP");
require("PATHTOTHEFILE/FILE.PHP"); 
require_once("PATHTOTHEFILE/FILE.PHP");
```

to include your class, or your code won't find it and will bug if you try to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

You must first run `composer update` in the MadelineProto repo, and then require it using 

`require 'vendor/autoload.php';`